# How to use OR in join while using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008

Can any one convert following SQL statement to Entity Framework C# or VB.net for me?

SQL statement:

```
 select t1.*, t2.* 
 from tblWISTransacs t1
 inner join tblWCBTransacs t2 on t1.TicketNo = t2.TicketNo 
                                 or t1.TicketNo = t2.customernumber
```

Comment: where did `a` and `b` come from?

Comment: That one is a typing mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = (from t1 in dbContext.tblWISTransacs
              join t2 in dbContext.tblWCBTransacs on 1 equals 1
              where (t1.TicketNo == t2.TicketNo || t1.TicketNo == t2.customernumber)
              select new { t1, t2 }).ToList();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The generated SQL is a bit different from Palani Kumar's, but you could also use

```
from t1 in db.tblWISTransacs
from t2 in db.tblWCBTransacs
where t1.TicketNo == t2.TicketNo || t1.TicketNo == t2.customernumber
select new { T1 = t1, T2 = t2 }
```

I think both end up essentially as a cross join.